# Zero-inflated models how to get predicted values = 0 stata

Tags: stata, panel-data, zero-inflation, diagnostic

I'm fairly new at Stata and this is the main reason of my question. I did a longitudinal zero-inflated poisson model:

```
xi:zip count variables, inflate(variables) vce(cluster id)
```

I tried to analyse the model afterwards with predict. However, the predicted number of events does not return any zero. I would like to compare the observed values with the adjusted values but I'm not sure how to get the predicted number of zeros.

Thank you for your help! Any pointer is appreciated since I'm new in Stata and zero-inflated models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zip model consists of two parts: a probability that the respondent is always 0 regardless of the explanatory variables and a predicted count if the respondent is not an "always 0". So the expected outcome is pr*0 + (1-pr)*predicted_count, and should thus not be 0 exactly.

To get the predicted number of always 0s (which ignores the number of 0s happening in the expected count part) you can predict the probability of being an "always 0" and show the sum:

```
predict pr if e(sample), pr 
sum pr 
di r(sum)
```

You can also look at [margdistfit](http://maartenbuis.nl/software/margdistfit.html), which graphically does what you want for all observed counts.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! Can you please explain with more detail your code? Why do you use if e(sample)? The package you show would be very helpful! Do you know if it works with longitudinal models as well?

Comment: `e(sample)` ensures that only those observations are used that were also used in the model. `margdistfit` works with `zip`, but `zip` is not a longitudinal model.

Comment: I'm comparing this model with a GLMM NB. It would be useful to be able to use also this package